# unlocking bootloader moto g xt1033

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to root my MOTO G XT1033 DUAL SIM but in the videos I've seen till date it says that you need unlock the boot loader .I saw solution videos to unlock boot loader but all of them says that by unlocking boot loader you will lose all your data.
So I was wondering that is there any way to unlock the MOTO G's boot loader without losing the data?
If it's not possible then please tell me how to unlock the boot loader without PC (my PC is damaged)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unlock your bootloader without also wiping your data. Backup your data, either manually or using an app. You also need a computer to perform the unlock process because it is performed while your device is in fastboot mode; before the Android OS is even started.